# Jquery UI navbar, hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working in this for a while and I am struggling to find a solution.

I am using bootstrap along with jquery. I have created this code which displays a dropdown menu with id of #drop when hovering over a list item with the id of #slider. Right now this code displays the extra dropdown menu(#drop) fine with no lag or glitching. All I want it to do now is disappear again when the mouse leaves the now visible element(#drop).

I have tried a few different methods including mouseout() and mouseleave() but nothing seems to make the element dissapear. Here is the code:

```
$('#slider').hover
   (function(){
    $("#drop").stop(true,true).hide().removeClass('hide').slideDown('slow');
        },
        function(){
        $("#drop").stop(true,true);
        }
  );
```

Any help with this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle.

```
$("#slider").toggle(function (){

$("#hover").stop().show();

},function (){

$("#hover").stop().hide();

});
```

Comment: I tried using the toggle class but no success, would the fact that I am using bootstrap cause complications?